# How is gamebench implemented to calculate the FPS of unity3d games?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

How does Frame per second of the unity3d game engine on android mobiles captured using gamebench

Tried using the gfxinfo over adb commands, doesnt help much ?

Need more help how to calculate the FPS of unity3d games on Android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it uses these commands [programmatically]:

(1) `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency-clear`

(2) `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency <window name>`

e.g.,

```
adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings

RefreshPeriod <-- Time in nano seconds
desiredPresentTime actualPresentTime frameReadyTime <-- Time in nano seconds
desiredPresentTime actualPresentTime frameReadyTime
desiredPresentTime actualPresentTime frameReadyTime
...
```

On how to interpret the results, see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/build/+/fefabac95d6aee4d941111e67f606dc50dfe9dd1/android/pylib/perf/surface_stats_collector.py#215 
and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/86efcc0/services/surfaceflinger/FrameTracker.cpp#217