# What is the "window name" in android?

Tags: android, adb

I want to execute the adb command "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency[window name]". But I don't know what "window name" means. What does that mean, and how do you get it?

Comment: Read this : ftp://fizika2.kee.hu/_Szaft1/08b_java/androidSDK/platform-tools/systrace/catapult/devil/devil/android/perf/surface_stats_collector.py

Comment: The page is not displayed.

Comment: You have to use "SurfaceView" window name. Like this 'dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency SurfaceView'

Comment: So, what is "SurfaceView window name"? I want you to be specific, not give me a rough idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the window name in which you are interested.
You can get the window name by tapping on the activity window you are interested in and then typing

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
```

Here is what you will get something like this

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{a3dfcbc u0 com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{27e3a63 token=Token{d08ff65 ActivityRecord{973205c u0 com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main t647}}}
```

Here your window is `com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697737/how-is-gamebench-implemented-to-calculate-the-fps-of-unity3d-games) is link for more information.